# Why is store bought frozen food worse than homemade?

Tags: flavor, freezing, food-preservation

I made multiple dishes following recipes and froze them, and they tasted a lot better than store-bought equivalents.

Why does it happen? Isn't current technology capable of doing the same procedures that one would do in their house and freezing it?

Or maybe is that too expensive to have enough public buying it?

I thought that the worse taste of store bought product was merely the act of freezing but it looks that is not the case.

Comment: @Catija You might consider posting roughly that as an answer.

Comment: +1.  The example that I cannot get my head around is chicken portions.  You can buy fresh chicken portions and freeze them yourself and they are fine.  You buy frozen chicken portions and they are always freezer burnt.  I do not get it.

Answer (score 8):

I think that at the end of the day, store bought frozen meals aren't per se worse, but rather that the manufacturer needs to appeal to a large, diverse audience of buyers and so their recipes are not tailored to your tastes. Recipes you make at home are often tailored to your taste by the mere fact that you selected the recipe and you know what you like.

They also need to use ingredients that they can get in large quantities, so the individual ingredients may not be the ripest or most flavorful variety (think tomatoes or apples).

Some things frozen at the store are probably better than at home, such as frozen vegetables or sometimes canned tomatoes. They usually have better technology to freeze the vegetables in the most efficient manner that best preserves their important qualities.

Comment: The other "large quantity" thing here is the preparation. Mass-produced food is obviously not the same as a small batch at home; a more fair comparison would be an extremely high-volume restaurant or cafeteria.

Comment: On the other hand, I guess most everyone here has at least a few times made something that was considered restaurant quality by a small audience ... this is unlikely with a bought frozen meal :) Maybe we pick not just our recipes but our audiences accordingly :)